# Difference between decrement and subtraction in 68HC12

Tags: assembly, binary, 68hc12

I'm using the HC12 chip.

We have instructions `SUBA` and `DECA`. The way you use `SUBA` is by subtracting some value (either in memory or a value you specify) from register A. `DECA` however takes no parameters and just subtracts $01 from register A. So my question is what is the difference between the instructions `SUBA #01` and `DECA`? My guess was that they behaved differently on negative numbers, but I am not entirely sure.
The question I'm dealing with:

```
      LDAA #230 ; 8 bit system, so this number is technically -26 in 2s complement. Register A is 8 bits, with LDAA loading into register A
LOOP: SUBA #01
      BGT LOOP
; rest of code
```

Would the code above work differently if `SUBA #01` was replaced with `DECA`?

Comment: That's not x86 code.  I think you mean 68hc12.  Also, `#230` fits in a 16-bit integer.  Did you mean *8-bit* where `230 == -26` in 2's complement?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant - the hc12 chip's D register is A reg + B reg, with A and B being 8 bits each, which is why I said 16 bit.

Comment: Ok, but `ldaa` loads the 8-bit A register.  If you consider the whole B:A = D register, the upper half is unset.  Or if it's zero, then you have `230`, *not* `-26`.  You'd only get `-26` from sign-extending 8-bit `230` into 16-bit D which your code doesn't do.  You're only working with 8-bit A with your load-immediate and `suba`.

Comment: I apologize for messing up - should I be changing the tag? I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I already changed the tag for you from x86 to 68hc12

Comment: That's great - thanks!

Comment: Except for the instruction size difference, `INCx` and `DECx` do not affect the CCR[C] flag (carry) whereas `ADDx` and `SUBx` do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DECA` is a very common operation and thus the ability to encode it in a smaller instruction was deemed worth its redundancy.

Comment: @cyber101: the same reasoning as this HC12 answer also applies to x86-16, except that x86 `dec` leaves CF unmodified, making it useful in `adc` / `sbb` or other loops where you want CF to survive a loop iteration.